# Moving printf to different lines gives different outputs? (C)

Tags: c, casting, int, printf

In C, when I move this printf line: `printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);` to different lines its output changes. Any ideas?

Heres the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{   

    int a = 65;
    char c = (char)a;
    int m = 3.0/2;

    printf("%c\n", c);              
    printf("%f\n", (float)a);       
    printf("%f\n", 5.0 / 2);        
    printf("%f\n", 5 / 2.0);        
    printf("%f\n", (float)5 / 2);   
    printf("%f\n", 5 / (float)2); 
    printf("%f\n", (float)(5 / 2)); 
    printf("%f\n", 5.0 / 2);        
    printf("%d\n", m);              
    printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);


    system("PAUSE");
    return(0);
}
```

And heres the output:

```
A
65.000000
2.500000
2.500000
2.500000
2.500000
2.000000
2.500000
1
2.500000
```

And if I move `printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);` to one of the first lines (between the one that outputs A and the one that outputs 65.000000) it will print 0.000000 (which makes sense) instead of its now 2.500000.
Any ideas?

Comment: `printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);` yields undefined behavior. The result of the (integer) division `5 / 2` is an integer operand with a value of `2`. You're attempting to print it in `float` format (let alone the fact that the compiler expands it to `double` before passing it to `printf`, so `printf` will attempt to read 8 bytes of data from the stack, while it holds only `sizeof(int)` bytes of data).

Comment: You can't print integers with `%f`, simple as that.

Comment: According to C99 standard regarding printf "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." (WG14 N1570, 7.21.6.1/p9).

Comment: ..so it has nothing to do with on which the pintf statement is, except that the stack containsd different (garbage) values when printf tries to interpret the integer as a double.

Comment: I'm very well aware that you cant print an integer with %f, I'm talking about printf("%f\n", 5 / 2); printing 2.500000 (take a look at the code again).

Comment: @SpacePotato Undefine Behavior permits anything can be the result. It might seem to work properly but fail mysteriously on making a slight change somewhere else in the code. BTW, aren't you getting warnings?

Comment: Well that's a silly question. You are asking "if I do something that is ill defined, what is the outcome?", but that's the very nature of being undefined behaviour, that there is no guaranteed outcome.

Comment: @SpacePotato Asking why undefined behavior does something is like asking why a specific uranium atom in a fissile rod underwent fission right this instant rather then 10 nanoseconds later: Theorethically determinable based on many factors, but wholly irrelevant to anything.

Comment: Nominating to reopen, per [this argument in meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271418/824425). As demonstrated in my answer, this UB is easy to predict and explain for common implementations on x86-64, and might help OP and other visitors to understand how this behaviour comes to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commenters have indicated, the line `printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);` simply exhibits undefined behaviour. But let's see why you might get results like these on an x86-64 architecture using the System V ABI.

The short answer is that the first few arguments are communicated through registers. The choice depends on the type of argument: integer arguments go in "classic" registers (`edi`, `esi`, etc.), floating-point go in SSE registers (`xmm0`, `xmm1`, etc.).

Because we're giving the wrong type in the format string, `printf` is reading the argument from the wrong register.

---

Let's simplify your program to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", 5/2);
    printf("%f\n", 5.0/2);
    printf("%f\n", 5/2);

    return 0;
}
```

Let's now walk through the disassembly of `main`. We start off with the function prologue, which isn't too special:

```
   push   %rbp
   mov    %rsp,%rbp
   sub    $0x10,%rsp
```

Then, we get our first call to `printf`, where the arguments are passed to `edi` (which gets a pointer to the format string) and `esi` (`5/2`, which is `2` due to integer division):

```
   mov    $0x2,%esi
   mov    $0x4005e4,%edi
   mov    $0x0,%eax
   callq  4003e0 <printf@plt>
```

However, `printf` will read the `"%f\n"` format and try to read the argument from `xmm0`. In my case, this register has the value `0`, so this prints out `0.000000`.

In the second call, the argument is obviously a floating-point number, which gets passed through `xmm0`:

```
   movabs $0x4004000000000000,%rax
   mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   movsd  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
   mov    $0x4005e4,%edi
   mov    $0x1,%eax
   callq  4003e0 <printf@plt>
```

Now, `printf` prints out the expected `2.500000` (which you see here as `0x4004000000000000`, which is what the 64-bit floating-point constant for 2.5 looks like). We pass it through `xmm0`, and it reads it from `xmm0`.

The third call is exactly the same as the first:

```
   mov    $0x2,%esi
   mov    $0x4005e4,%edi
   mov    $0x0,%eax
   callq  4003e0 <printf@plt>
```

What has changed is that the calls to `printf` didn't change the value in `xmm0`. It still contains the constant 2.5 from before the second call as we call `printf` for the third time. In the third call, `printf` will print `2.500000` again.

(And our function ends with a boring `return 0`, of course:)

```
   mov    $0x0,%eax
   leaveq 
   retq
```

Comment: What the compiler is doing to `eax` isn't worth much more than a footnote here: in the SysV x86-64 ABI, `eax` is involved with the argument lists of variadic functions, such as `printf`. Theoretically, `printf` could have detected that there's something wrong with its arguments (it gets `eax = 0` in the UB calls and `eax = 1` in the correct call). In practice, the `printf` implementation doesn't notice this because `<stdarg.h>` doesn't make this distinction.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is invoking undefined behavior.

You are obligated to use the correct data specifiers for printing things in `printf`, and failing to do so is invoking UB. Thus it is unimportant and not surprising that you get different results at different places.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

The same holds true for just c.

When invoking undefined behavior, the results are by definition random and not predictable, so asking us to predict them makes little sense.